# Why URL::defaults() is not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass the variable to default route generator.

I do that in `Company.php` middleware:

```
$company_user = CompanyUser::where([
          ['user_id', \Auth::id()],
          ['company_id', $request->route('company')]
        ])->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();
$company = \App\Company::find($request->route('company'));
\URL::defaults(compact('company'));
```

Then any try to generate any company path throws an exception with "Missing route parameters" message.

I tried to get the default route parameters in controller:

```
dd(URL::getDefaultParameters());
```

And there's the company I passed from middleware:

```
array:1 [▼
  "company" => App\Company {#583 ▶}
]
```

So why can't I generate route without passing company parameter from controller/service/view if I have the company in default route parameters ?

Comment: why are you giving it the entity, when the route need an id ? try `$company = $request->route('company');`

Comment: Can you provide the content of the `/routes/` directory which shows the route you are trying to access? It could be that the route is expecting a parameter you haven't actually provided. This could be something other than "company"

Comment: @N69S Laravel can work with entities in route parameters, so it works when I pass the company model to the route generator.

Comment: @Spholt the error is `Missing required parameters for [Route: company.bots.telegram] [URI: company/{company}/bots/telegram].`, so there's no another route parameters.

Comment: @N69S you was right. More info in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

@N69S was right.

Laravel can work with passing model to route generator to use it as parameter, but Laravel can't work with it from default URL parameters. So the decision is to pass the ID of the company to default URL parameters, not model.

So, it works with:

```
\URL::defaults([
    'company' => $company->id
]);
```